# Building a windows application. How and What?

Tags: c#, database, windows, exe

Basically I wanted to know which technology and languages should I use if I wanted to build a windows application. My requirements are:

- my application must be able to store data entries.
- a simple GUI.
- I should be able to distribute my application as an .exe file

I did some research and found out that I should use C# and wrap a mysql db in my application. Is this the correct way or is there any other and better method than this?

I am a newbie developer and have worked only with java, so please bare if its a silly question.

Comment: How much research did you do before you reached the conclusion to use a wrapper? [Connecting to a MySql server](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp) is just a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx) away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will always be arguments over the 'correct way' and whether one method is 'better' than another.  Threre are also a couple of 'it depends' aspects to your question.

Having said that, yes, C# is a well recognised technology for developing windows applications, and mysql will provide a means to add database abilities to the application, so you are well on the way.  (Trust your research :).

Do you intend to develop a multi user application that takes data from different sources?  For this, you will need to think about deploying the database separately to the application and network/internet access etc etc.  Also, if this is the case, you may want to think about a more robust database solution like sql server.  There are a number of versions of this database (see here for some info: http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server-2012/sql-server-2012-editions-142261).

If your application is going to be standalone, then deploying an instance of mysql within the application will work, but you may want to consider something with a smaller footprint (sql server compact, or sql lite maybe).

hth

Answer (score 1):

Aside from learning C#, as you know Java already, you can also develop a Java app and use a wrapper tool like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net) and [jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/download.php) to distribute it on Windows and have it configured to automatically install JRE if there's none.

Comment: I was thinking of the same at start but many said its not advisable as it goes against the java's cross platform concept and also java doesn't give a native feeling. One more reason for not going with this method was that the chance of clashes between my application and any other application on clients machine for the requirement of jre. For example it might require a older version of jre to run smoothly and my application may require a newer version of jre.

Comment: Though these seem like reasonable reservations, I used to be involved in QA'ing an in-house application for a large company that was actually a Java app in a wrapper. Updating the application was little more than replacing the jar file and keeping everything else intact. It worked quite well. I personally don't think applications these days give a "native feeling" (look at Google Chrome and Firefox for example and examine how un-native they actually look and feel), and just because  Java is portable doesn't mean you have to make your application portable as well :). Just my two cents.

Comment: Also JREs are generally backwards compatible (see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html#incompatibilities for exceptions) so there are no usually no worries with upgrading the JREs.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Will consider using java again.

Answer (score 0):

for a newbie for such a nice and clear question. Yes you can use C#  with windows form to build up your app. But You cannot pack you db inside an exe. It must be an external resource. Better go for C# with SQL Server as Sql Server is its native and has far better support than any database available. Also you have express edition of the same to use upto 10GB and most important its free....

Answer (score 0):

As per my concern you can go with c# application. But nobody can tell whether it is simple to you or not. It depends on how you understand the concepts and syntax of the language. I recommend you to go with C# and MS SQL Sever Express Edition.